# Read Excel file from python pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am unable to read this type of excel file from pandas in python.

[image]

[image: This is the excel file]

Comment: "unable to read this type of excel file." What exactly is the error you're facing? What have you tried so far to read the file? Please post a minimally reproducible example from your code along with a small sample of your data as text (not an image)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Although cannot understand your situation best from picture.

Still recommend to Try to read file with following code might help, where you need to add extra parameters which will help to filter some unnecessary info.

```
pd.read_excel(full_path, sheet_name = 'Daily Report', skiprows = <rowsyouwnttoskip>,  nrows= <yourlastrow>, usecols = f'D:Z')
```

**note:** I havenot add the exact value in above code, edit as per your need

Then you need to apply addition cleaning such as take your first row as column names, and etc.

**Update:**  you can use additonal function as below

```
def convert_xls_to_xlsx(p , f): #P stands for Path and F for file name with extension
    oldFile = os.path.abspath(p + '\\' +f)
    newFile = os.path.abspath(p + '\\' +f[:f.find('.')])
    xlApp = Dispatch('Excel.Application')
    wb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(oldFile)
    wb.SaveAs(newFile,51)
    wb.Close(True)
    os.remove(oldFile)
```

Comment: Thank You, It is working perfectly.

Also can you tell that how to read xls file, it is generating this error whie reading " raise CompDocError(msg)
xlrd.compdoc.CompDocError: MSAT extension: accessing sector 131072 but only 22863 in file"

Comment: Thank You, But I am not working with file system, I am getting xls from Azure Blob, is this  anyway to convert from azure blob.

Comment: I would recommend you to raise another question for it, as it different and vast topic.

Answer (score 0):

You can read xlsx file using openpyxl engine.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('C://Users//jahir//Desktop//file_name.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')
print(df)
```